# Propel ORM including MAX in criteria

Tags: propel

I am writing a query using the Propel ORM

The query is of the form:

```
select * from some_table where some_table.created_at = (SELECT MAX(some_table.created_at) from some_table);
```

I got this far:

```
 $c = new Criteria();
 $c->addSelectColumn('MAX('.self::CREATED_AT.')');
```

Anyone knows how to use Propel to do this, to save me writing RAW SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(SomeTable::CREATED_AT, '(SELECT MAX('.SomeTable::CREATED_AT.') FROM some_table)', Criteria::CUSTOM);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you jhust want to know how to add custom `WHERE` values, then the solution by @prodigitalson should work, but I wonder why you are doing it this way in the first place versus just:

```
$recs = SomeTableQuery::create()->orderByCreatedAt()->findOne();
```

...which will get you the latest created record.

Comment: this helped me out thanks.  I was also looking to get the MAX value of a certain column but your method works wonderfully.  Simply order that column desc and findone.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing. Like I said, just wanted to mention a possible alternate solution to the business problem versus just how to use `MAX()`.

Answer (score 1):

This way is not mentioned - so this works for me:

```
MyTable::create() 
->select('max_id') 
->addAsColumn('max_id', 'MAX(id)')
->findOne();
```

find() returns a collection of objects so use findOne()

addAsColumn() returns just the selected column.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get ->withColumn('MAX(itemrevisionID)') to work, so the work around was this ->orderByitemrevisionID('desc')