# How can I retrieve the latest question of each thread in Propel 1.6?

Tags: propel

I want to get the **newest entries** for each of my threads (private messaging system) with Propel 1.6 making use of the **fluid ModelQuery** interface. This would allow me to reuse both methods for getting newest entries and only getting entries where a user is involved (nobody wants to see messages not for him).

I already found out that in standard-SQL I have to use a subquery to [get the newest entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404/sql-query-to-get-latest-price) for each of my forum threads. I also found out that in Propel you have to use a [Criteria::CUSTOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868673/propel-orm-including-max-in-criteria) query to achieve this, but the whole Criteria::CUSTOM stuff seems to be pre-Propel-1.6, because none of the examples makes use of the new ModelQuery.

Now the problem is, that I want to make use of the concenation feature in ModelQueries, where you can attach several own methods to each other like this:

```php
$entries = MessageQuery::create()
     ->messagesInvolvingUser($user) // user retrieved or sent the message
     ->newestFromThread() // get the latest entry from a lot of Re:-stuff
```

I do not think that this would still be possible if I had to use

```php
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add([the subquery filter]);
```

in `newestFromThread()`.

What’s the best method to retrieve the latest entry for each thread given the following scheme (`thread_id` means that all messages belong to the same correspondence, I want only one entry per `thread_id`):

```sql
id(INT)
title(VARCHAR)
thread_id(INTEGER)
date(DATETIME)
```

The current PHP-implementation looks like this:

```php
<?php

class MessageQuery extends BaseMessageQuery {
    public function messagesInvolvingUser($user) {
        return $this
            ->where('Message.AuthorId = ?', $user->getId())
            ->_or()
            ->where('Message.RecipientId = ?', $user->getId());
    }

    public function newestFromThread() {
        return $this;
        // To be implemented
    }
}
```

And I am using it like this:

```php
$messages = MessageQuery::create()
    ->messagesInvolvingUser(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity())
    ->newestFromThread()
    ->find();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the answers in a similar question about [pure SQL solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404/sql-query-to-get-latest-price), I guess it is easiest to add a new column **newest** indicating which message in a communcation is the newest. This probably fits the object-oriented approach of Propel better, too. I could write my application like this then:

```php
public function preInsert(PropelPDO $con = null) {
    $this->setNewest(1);
    $this->getEarlier()->setNewest(0);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about ordering results by date (DESC) and to limit to one result ?